# Not getting any value in controller page using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am not getting any value from drop down list in controller file using angular.js.It is simple throwing following error.

```
$scope.subname is undefined
```

I am explaining my code below.

**index.html**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="tableCtrl">
    <tr>
        <td width="100" align="center">Time <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i>
            <BR>Day <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></i>
        </td>
        <td width="100" align="center" ng-repeat="hour in hours" ng-bind="hour"></td>
    </tr>
    <tbody id="detailsstockid">
        <tr ng-repeat="days in noOfDays">
            <td width="100" align="center" style=" vertical-align:middle" ng-bind="days"></td>
            <td width="100" align="center" style="padding:0px;" ng-repeat="hour in hours" >
                <table style="margin:0px; padding:0px; width:100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select id="coy" name="coy" class="form-control" ng-model="subname">
                                <option value="">Select Cource</option>
                                <option value="A">Theory1</option>
                                <option value="B">Theory2</option>
                                <option value="C">Theory3</option>
                                <option value="D">Theory4</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select id="coy" name="coy" class="form-control" ng-model="facname" ng-change="readData();">
                                <option value="">Select Faculty</option>
                                <option value="A">Faculty1</option>
                                <option value="B">Faculty2</option>
                                <option value="C">Faculty3</option>
                                <option value="D">Faculty4</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**script.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.controller('tableCtrl', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {

        $scope.noOfDays = [];

        $scope.days = {
          '0': "Monday",
          '1': 'Tuesday',
          '2': 'Wednesday',
          '3': 'Thursday',
          '4': 'Friday'
        }

        $scope.hours = [
          '9AM :: 10AM',
          '10AM :: 11AM',
          '11:15AM :: 12:15PM',
          '12:15PM :: 01:15PM',
          '02PM :: 03PM',
          '03PM :: 04PM',
          '04PM :: 05PM'
        ]

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          $scope.noOfDays.push($scope.days[i]);
        }
         $scope.readData=function(){
         alert($scope.subname.value,$scope.facname.value);
         }
      }]);
```

Here when the ng-change event is executing that error is coming.I need when user will select any course data and faculty name ,it will store in a json variable with day and time.Here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/W0wwBzGGL35igEYzgAWD?p=preview) example.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `ng-model="facname"` and `ng-model="subname"` but for getting value you have used

```
alert($scope.subname.value,$scope.facname.value);
```

which will not work because `$scope.subname` **needs to define** in controller. But you can pass it to method and get in controller function like

```
$scope.readData = function(subname, facname, days, hour) {
      alert('name : ' + subname + ', facname : ' + facname + ', days : ' + days + ', hours : ' + hour);
}
```

and in HTML

```
<select id="coy" name="coy" class="form-control" ng-model="facname" ng-change="readData(subname, facname, days, hour);">
```

Check `ng-change` function passes four arguments. You can **directly** pass `modal` value to function and access that value in controller function.

**Note**: If first dropdown is not selected and set to default value then by changing second dropdown return `undefined` for `subname`

Snippet for more details:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.controller('tableCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {

    $scope.noOfDays = [];
    //$scope.subname = '';
    //$scope.facname = '';

    $scope.days = {
      '0': "Monday",
      '1': 'Tuesday',
      '2': 'Wednesday',
      '3': 'Thursday',
      '4': 'Friday'
    }

    $scope.hours = [
      '9AM :: 10AM',
      '10AM :: 11AM',
      '11:15AM :: 12:15PM',
      '12:15PM :: 01:15PM',
      '02PM :: 03PM',
      '03PM :: 04PM',
      '04PM :: 05PM'
    ]

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      $scope.noOfDays.push($scope.days[i]);
    }
    $scope.readData = function(subname, facname, days, hour) {
      alert('name : ' + subname + ', facname : ' + facname + ', days : ' + days + ', hours : ' + hour);
    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="tableCtrl">
  <tr>
    <td width="100" align="center">Time <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i>
      <BR>Day <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></i>
    </td>
    <td width="100" align="center" ng-repeat="hour in hours" ng-bind="hour"></td>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="detailsstockid">
    <tr ng-repeat="days in noOfDays">
      <td width="100" align="center" style=" vertical-align:middle" ng-bind="days"></td>
      <td width="100" align="center" style="padding:0px;" ng-repeat="hour in hours">
        <table style="margin:0px; padding:0px; width:100%">

          <tr>
            <td>
              <select id="coy" name="coy" class="form-control" ng-model="subname">
                <option value="">Select Cource</option>
                <option value="A">Theory1</option>
                <option value="B">Theory2</option>
                <option value="C">Theory3</option>
                <option value="D">Theory4</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <select id="coy" name="coy" class="form-control" ng-model="facname" ng-change="readData(subname, facname, days, hour);">
                <option value="">Select Faculty</option>
                <option value="A">Faculty1</option>
                <option value="B">Faculty2</option>
                <option value="C">Faculty3</option>
                <option value="D">Faculty4</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @ Sarjan :Thanks its the one solution.But here i also need when 1st ng-change event will execute i got the subname anf facname but i should also get the respective day and time slot along with it and save them into a json variable.I have already created the plunkr please check .